# How to move from testrpc development to geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, testnets

I've made an application in nodejs in which I'm doing truffle migrate to deploy contract and it make my contract's build saving my ABI which i use for contract invocation and the http provider for web3 is localhost:8545???
How should I switch to Geth environment if I want to test it on a public test network?? Been stuck at this query, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start geth:

```
geth --testnet --fast --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

And use this RPC address (localhost:8545) at your nodejs application to do truffle migrate.

Do this way, if you are talking about Ropsten public testnet.

In the case of Kovan public testnet, start parity at the same address:

```
parity --chain=kovan
```